# unique-constraint in liferay service builder

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

How can i configure the service builder to generate a query with Unique key constraint?
Is there any way to do this? Does liferay supports this requirement?
Or we have to do this manually in our codebase?

Currently I'm using Liferay 6.2 CE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's easy, here an example:

```
    <!-- PK fields -->

    <finder name="M_N" return-type="MachineDevice" unique="true">
        <finder-column name="machineId" />
        <finder-column name="nodeId" />
    </finder>
```

Comment: Yep got it. I thought this code is for finders. But it is adding unique key constraint in indexes.sql file. 
And one other question here:

I want to validate the UI fields with Unique key constraint with this change. So is there any internal implementation available in liferay or do we need to add any extra logic for this?

Comment: For the UI you have many built-in validators, see https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/using-the-alloyui-form-validator-in-a-portlet.
But for the unique checking you have to implements your own validator server side (using finder) and manage user feedback.